# Git lost history whereas I only renamed the file without changing content

Tags: git

According to this article https://coderwall.com/p/_csouq/renaming-and-changing-files-in-git-without-losing-history

Git will not lose history when renaming if content doesn't change. When I tried at least in VSCode it doesn't seem true.

Am I wrong or is the article wrong ? Information on Internet about that subject are so contradictory.

Comment: Git doesn't keep "file history". If you rename a file and also change it's contents, git doesn't know that they're the same file. You'd have to mark it as such using `git mv`

Comment: @evolutionxbox To be clear since this is a common point of confusion: `git mv` doesn't do anything special to indicate to Git that a file was moved.  It is simply shorthand for `mv old new && git rm old && git add new`.  Changing file contents in the same commit as a `git mv` will still cause the exact same problems.

Comment: @0x5453 oh interesting. I had always thought it gave extra information to git. Like "intent-to-add".

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

`git log --follow file` will find renaming operations if the file is kept identical or very similar in the commit where it is renamed.

#### Details

When you have renamed files, `git log --follow file` does a best effort to figure out what renaming operations `file` underwent. If you have a commit that has only and exactly the `git mv` operation, figuring it out is trivial and works every time. If you rename and modify in the same commit, you make the problem harder. Sometimes `git log --follow file` does figure it out, but not always.

The major caveat, of course, is that `git log --follow` works only on one file at a time. So you've kept the history, yes, but it's a fair amount of work if you want to track all the renames that have happened.

#### A tested example

I just created a file, then renamed and modified it slightly in the same commit:

```
seq 1 100 > seq
git add seq
git commit -m'seq: count to 100'
git mv seq seq2
echo 101 >> seq2
git add seq2
git commit -m'git mv seq seq2 and append 101'
```

At this point, `git log --follow` traced `seq2` to `seq`, finding the renaming operation even though it was combined with a (very small) content change.

Now, let's do a bigger change:

```
git mv seq2 seq3
seq 200 300 >> seq3
git add seq3
git commit -m'git mv seq2 seq2 + append 200..300'
```

Now Git lost track of the rename: `git log --follow seq3` found only the one commit that created it and stopped there. I had to do `git log --follow -- seq2` to get the older history involving `seq2` and `seq`.

There's probably some documentation somewhere about how much change Git will tolerate and still find the renames, but I don't know where.

#### Space efficiency

There is also the consideration of space efficiency, mentioned in the link you shared: if your `git mv` operation stands alone in a commit with no other file changes, the last commit of the old file and the first commit of the new file will share the same blob (that always happens when two files are identical), and other commits will be able to be stored as change sets. If you make edits when you rename, you prevent Git from doing this optimization since it's not creating a link between the two names.

Comment: git log --follow file : VSCode has a timeline section it doesn't take this into account ?

Comment: @user310291 This [vscode issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94803) says they don't plan to address renames in the Timeline View, after trying and failing to do so, for reasons explained there. So no, apparently not.